# SFTP visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have to send file using SFTP in VS2013 (C#). what's the best way to do this?
Not sure if there are any built in libraries for this functionality or I have to do with 3rd party.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do:  Use a feature in Visual Studio to upload a file yourself, or write some code to send a file via sftp?

Comment: I've looked, specifically this past year, for this same functionality to use in one of my projects and no domino. 
I did come across a useful library that I am now using and works well. It's not free unfortunately but it is useful. 
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ .. 
This assumes of course that you are trying to write an application that uses SFTP.

Comment: You can also look at WinSCP. It has a managed code wrapper that allows for controlling SFTP sessions from C# and other .NET languages. http://winscp.net/eng/index.php. WinSCP is free but unlike Chilkat it is not all managed code.

Comment: I have looked at chilkatsoft and Winscp. I might go with one of these free utilities.

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720370/Easy-SFTP-Secure-FTP-With-Csharp-and-PSFTP

Maybe this link be useful for you.

Regards,

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is the fact that you have to use an application like PuTTy to accept the certificate first. Otherwise, it seems okay for a free solution.

Comment: Yes: I don't found anymore solution. I wish it helps the user for his question.

Comment: I agree. It's better than nothing. If the OP could find a way to somehow automate the certificate process then this would be perfect.

Comment: I have seen this link, and that's why I was wondering if there is any better option.

Comment: If you had more than one project that needed to use SFTP then I would say buy Chilkat's SFTP solution but if it's only one project then you may have to get into the nitty gritty of something like this. There does not appear to be many free options for SFTP unfortunately.